# Java variables in urls

Tags: java, html, variables

I would like to ask how I could make it, so that users on my website could enter a value (lets say they enter 21) and then once they hit submit it will open a URL with that variable in it (also it must be a sub-domain) so the user would now be redirected to

> 21.mydomain.com

Thank You

Comment: Also I would love if it could be in html or Java

Comment: your question is not cleared

Comment: I haven't tried much so far ( I'm not a developer). Ankit basically what I want is an input field (like when you enter your username) that when they have entered there info it will open up a url with there info in it. For example: I enter Tim and click enter this should now open up   Tim.mysite.com.    Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very easy.

You can:

```
System.out.print("Enter a subdomain: ");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String subdomain = sc.next();
URI url = new URI("http://" + subdomain + ".domain.com");
Desktop d = Desktop.getDesktop();
d.browse(url);
```

Comment: Thanks very much, May I also ask how I would integrate this into html I tried using the <script> tags but it didn't work. Thanks

Comment: You can't. Java != JavaScript.

Comment: You could integrate java scripts/applets, but it's discouraged.

Comment: You can make this with JavaScript also, I'll provide you that code in about 1 hour, because I'm gonna have lunch now...

Comment: Ok thanks. Sorry Iam so inexperienced. I have to be able to put this in a html file. Thanks

Comment: Here you are: http://pastebin.com/jtAXjuj4

Comment: Thank you  dude :)

Comment: Leave a +1 if I helped

Comment: One more question are there any server side requirements for this? I haven't tried it on my site yet, but previewing it on html test sites it only worked on one of them.

Comment: No, there are no requirements. The only requirement is that the visitor must have JavaScript enabled.